# how to call a jquery function on a variable?

Tags: jquery, function, call

I am trying to call a jquery function call on a variable, but it is not working. Please help.

```
<div class="component_id">'#test1'</div>
var comp_id = $( "div.component_id" ).text();
jQuery(''+ comp_id +'').dcSocialStream({
});
```

Comment: "it is not working" is never a good problem description. What exactly goes wrong? What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: ok thanks, i will make a note in future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your selector is invalid because it has enclosing `''`, in your console you should see the error `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#test1'` - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qw6EK/1/)

Remove them in the div content

```
<div class="component_id">#test1</div>

var comp_id = $( "div.component_id" ).text();
jQuery($.trim(comp_id)).dcSocialStream({
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qw6EK/3/)

or use javascript to remove them like

```
var comp_id = $.trim($( "div.component_id" ).text()).replace(/^'|'$/g, '');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qw6EK/4/)

Comment: HI,
Thanks this worked!
can i even append # in jquery itself?
In comp_id instead of giving in div

    <div class="component_id">test1</div>
    //how to append # in comp_id string?
    var comp_id = $.trim($( "div.component_id" ).text());
    jQuery(comp_id).text('found');